# Click on Captcha via Selenium always raised picture verification

Tags: c#, selenium, captcha

So i try to send `SMS` using [this](https://globfone.com/send-text) site via `Selenium`.

After choose my country and my phone number i have this `Captcha`:

[image]

So with `Selenium` i succeed to click on this `Checkbox` but allways got this `image verification`:

[image]

i try to put several sleeps before this `Checkbox` click but this `image verification` is still exist.
This behavior is not hapenning via manual scenarion so my question is why this is happening ?

This is how i am find my elements and click on `Captcha` Checkbox:

```
IWebElement frame = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//iframe[contains(@src, 'recaptcha')]"))[0];
driver.SwitchTo().Frame(frame);

IWebElement checkbox = Driver.Browser.FindElement(By.CssSelector("div.recaptcha-checkbox-checkmark"));
checkbox.click();
```

Answer (score 4):

This is the whole point of `captcha's` that bot do-not pass a certain point/crawl a webpage; This appears when a website is suspicious of bot activity so just to make sure that a human is on another side these images are shown; so that only a human can be allowed further activity.

You don't get these images when you try to do that manually is because you verify this on local installation of a browser, which have constantly saved cookies about your activities; but when you launch the same screen via `Selenium WebDriver` a new fresh instance is launched and to make sure that instance/session is legit; websites can ask for `captcha` details,

But in order to circumvent this situation, you can try to use same sessions where you have already answered the questions, you can do this using `DesiredCapabilities` in `selenium`, please google for more.

Comment: Excellent idea. To make use of saved cookies. That should work.

Answer (score 1):

try logging into an old gmail account before attempting to click recaptcha automatically

Answer (score 0):

Take out side  beyond selenium , use Sikuli http://www.sikuli.org/ to click on the button and do your stuff Use Java Api of Sikuli not the IDE and use relative region.

> All though as mentioned above if you have the scope of the Dev also ,
>   speak with the Dev and turn off the Captcha from the flow

Comment: What do you mean Use Java Api of Sikuli not he IDE and use relative region ?

Answer (score 0):

import the sikuli jar into your project and use below code

```
package com.test;
import org.sikuli.script.FindFailed;
import org.sikuli.script.Screen;
public class CaptchaCick{
public static void main(String[] args) throws FindFailed, InterruptedException {

 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 Screen s=new Screen();
 s.find("source.png");
 s.click(("source.png");
 System.out.println("Source image found");
 }
```

}

Comment: Any solution for c# ?